# Flex: Read bytearray

Tags: apache-flex, filereference

I use the following to upload a file to Flex:

```
        private var filer:FileReference;
        protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var fd:String = "Files (*)"; 
            var fe:String = "*"; 
            var ff:FileFilter = new FileFilter(fd, fe);
            filer = new FileReference();
            filer.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, onFileSelect);
            filer.browse(new Array(ff));
            filer.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, 
                function (e:Event):void {
                    e.currentTarget.data.toString();
                }
            );
        }
        private function onFileSelect(e:Event):void {
            filer.load(); 
        }
```

And my file looks like this:
[image]

Here is the original file: http://sesija.com/up/1.txt

I need to read the uploaded file and parse it. The problem is that in my `e.currentTarget.data.toString();` I get only '`1`' and not the rest of the String.

Any idea on how to successfully read this entire txt file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [data](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#data) property is a [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html). Instead of using the `toString` method (which apparently treats NULL byte as end of string), use specific read methods of the ByteArray class like `readByte`, `readInt` etc.

```
var array:Array = [];
var ba:ByteArray = e.currentTarget.data as ByteArray;
while(ba.bytesAvailable != 0){
    array.push(ba.readByte());
}
trace(array.join(", "));
```

You might want to read [Working with byte arrays](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5388-8000.html)